# Make Start Menu in Mint/Cinnamon honor the "New windows use the default layout" setting

Tags: linux, linux-mint, keyboard-layout, cinnamon

I'm on Mint/Cinnamon (version is 17.1   Rebecca), and I've set my keyboard layout to "Allow different layouts" and "New windows use the default layout".

If I'm on a window with Cyrillic, and I create a new window, the new window starts with English layout, as it should. If I open the Start Menu, however, it starts with Cyrillic, not English.

Is there a way to make the start menu honor the "New windows use the default layout" setting?

Answer (score 0):

As of last time i checked Mint out (believe it was Quina (17) )  Start menu did not honour that natively only whatever the global value was which it appears not to be even doing..

What is the "default" keyboard layout by chance as English has like 18 options